# determining the image of a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm wondering what approach I should take to find the image of a linear operator: $T: \ell_2 \to \ell_2$ with $Tx = T[(x_n)_{n \ge 1}] = (\frac{x_n}{n})_{n \ge 1}$.

Now I know that since $T$ is clearly injective and $T^{-1}: T(\ell_2) \to \ell_2 $ is defined as $T^{-1}x = (n x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is clearly unbounded, that the image of $T$, $T \ell_2 $ is not closed, but I am interested in trying to actually show that explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $T$ is simply $\{(y_n)\in l^{2}: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{2}y_n^{2}<\infty\}$. This is not closed because the sequence $\{(1,\frac 1 {2^{3/4}},\frac 1 {3^{3/4}},...,\frac 1 {n^{3/4}},0,0,...)\}:n=1,2,...\}$ lies in the range and converges to $(1,\frac 1 {2^{3/4}},\frac 1 {3^{3/4}},...)$ which does not belong the range of $T$.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but shouldn't the range of $T$ actually be the space where $\sum y_n^2 / n^2 < \infty $ ?

Comment: If $(y_n)$ is in the range then there exits $(x_n)\in l^{2}$ such that $y_n=\frac {x_n} n$ for all $n$. Since $\sum_n x_n^{2} <\infty$ we get $\sum_n n^{2}y_n^{2} <\infty$.